# Javascript accessing the variable inside function

Tags: javascript

I came across website that contains below code.I need to get the value of `a`.In firefox webconsole i tried this ...`javascript:alert(_.Qj.a());` , but it did not work..how can i access the value of `a , c f` etc

```
    _.Qj = function () {
    function a() {
        var a = window.__OVERRIDE_SID;
        a == _.s && (a = _.Yj.get("SID"));
        return !!a
    }
    return {
        Nq: function (a) {
            var f = {
                SAPISIDHASH: _.r,
                APISIDHASH: _.r
            };
            return a && (a.OriginToken || a.Authorization && f[String(a.Authorization).split(" ")[0]]) ? _.r : _.u
        },
        er: a,
        bq: function () {
            var c = _.s;
            a() && (c = window.__PVT, c == _.s && (c = _.Yj.get("BEAT")));
            return c
        },
        Qe: function () {
            var c = _.Rb.Pq(String(window.location.href));
            if (a()) {
                var f = 0 == c.indexOf("https:") || 0 == c.indexOf("chrome-extension:"),
                    g = f ? "SAPISID" : "APISID",
                    h = f ? window.__SAPISID : window.__APISID;
                h == _.s && (h = _.Yj.get(g));
                if (h) return f = f ? "SAPISIDHASH" : "APISIDHASH", g = (0, _.Tb)(), g.reset(), g.update([h, c].join(" ")), f + " " + g.Of().toLowerCase()
            }
            return _.s
        }
    }
}();
```

and any basic explanation to this code will be appreciated

Comment: Are you honestly giving us minified, unformated code as an example?

Comment: i donno what kinda of code is this :( please explain what it is

Comment: Try pasting this into a website like http://jsbeautifier.org/, it will make this code significantly more readable.

Comment: @user2449384: This is minified code (think obfuscated). It's no good for a question.

Comment: @ elclanrs : how can i make it clean ?

Comment: Which of all those `a`s do you want to get? There are multiple! Some you can get and some you can't. If you don't provide more information, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you'd access `a`:

```
javascript:alert(_.Qj.er());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7HvS/) inspired by your code.

Comment: Try adding `var _ = _ || {};` above your snippet.

Comment: please check https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.hgKKOofQjvI.O/m=googleapis_client,iframes_styles_bubble_internal/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=EQ/rs=AItRSTOeNwU4i5ApX9gPGjnZ0AzovKWmWw/cb=gapi.loaded_0 , i want to read this code